# LINQ query to room bookings

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, visual-studio

hi everyone i want to get all the rooms that are available from the database. Below is the table structure:

Table Room:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Room] (
    [ID]            INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
);
```

Table Booking:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Booking] (
    [ID]               INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [RoomID]           INT            NOT NULL,
    [DateFrom]         DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [DateTo]           DATETIME       NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_Room] FOREIGN KEY ([RoomID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Room] ([ID]),

);
```

This is what i have done till now and it is not right.

```
var a = _RoomService.GetRooms()
 .Where(a => a.ID <> (_BookingService.GetBookings()
 .Where((b => b.DateFrom > thisDate.DateFrom || 
              b.DateFrom < thisDate.DateFrom && 
              b.DateTo > thisDate.DateTo || 
              b.DateTo < thisDate.DateTo))
 .ToList());
```

I want to get all the rooms that are available when a user chose a From Date and To Date. Thank you in anticipation.

**EDIT**

here is what i achieved but still no results..

```
var roomsBooked = from b in _BookingService.GetBookings()
                               where (b.DateFrom <= thisDate.DateFrom) && (b.DateTo >= thisDate.DateFrom) ||
                               (b.DateFrom <= thisDate.DateTo) && (b.DateTo <= thisDate.DateTo) ||
                               (b.DateFrom >= thisDate.DateFrom) && (b.DateTo >= thisDate.DateTo)
                               select b;


var availableRooms = _RoomService.GetRooms().Where(a => roomsBooked.Any(b => b.RoomID != a.ID));
```

Anyone who can help is welcome. i have been trying since yesterday:( Thank you

Comment: usually when dealing with Dates it's best to utilize the `>= or the <=` vs `> or <` perhaps this hint will help you figure it out..

Comment: *a.ID <> (...* ????? that's not C#, the "not equals" operator is !=, not <>...

Comment: @Gusman so you're saying `<> != !=`, but rather `!= = !=`?

Comment: instead of *a.ID <> (...* it should be *a.ID != (...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample I have put together for you.  It is exactly the same as @AD.Net asnwer, except that mine is written in LINQ. I have placed this is in a console application for you, that you can test and play around with if interested, just copy and paste.

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
    }

    public Program()
    {
        var _BookingService = new List<Booking>()
        {
            new Booking() { ID = 100, RoomID = 1, DateFrom = new DateTime(2016, 5, 15), DateTo = new DateTime(2016, 5, 17)},
            new Booking() { ID = 200, RoomID = 2, DateFrom = new DateTime(2016, 5, 20), DateTo = new DateTime(2016, 5, 25) }
        };

        this.DateFrom = new DateTime(2016, 5, 14);
        this.DateTo = new DateTime(2016, 5, 27);

        var roomsBooked = from b in _BookingService
                          where
                                  ((this.DateFrom >= b.DateFrom) && (this.DateFrom <= b.DateTo)) ||
                                  ((this.DateTo >= b.DateFrom) && (this.DateTo <= b.DateTo)) ||
                                  ((this.DateFrom <= b.DateFrom) && (this.DateTo >= b.DateFrom) && (this.DateTo <= b.DateTo)) ||
                                  ((this.DateFrom >= b.DateFrom) && (this.DateFrom <= b.DateTo) && (this.DateTo >= b.DateTo)) ||
                                  ((this.DateFrom <= b.DateFrom) && (this.DateTo >= b.DateTo))
                            select b;


        var availableRooms = GetRooms().Where(r => !roomsBooked.Any(b => b.RoomID == r.ID));

        foreach (var room in availableRooms)
            Console.WriteLine($"{room.Title}");

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public List<Room> GetRooms()
    {
        return new List<Room>()
        {
            new Room() { ID = 1, Title = "Room 1" },
            new Room() { ID = 2, Title = "Room 3" }
        };
    }
}

public class Room
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

}
public class Booking
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RoomID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
}
```

The juicy part, that you are interested in, is this piece of code:

```
var roomsBooked = from b in _BookingService
                          where
                                  ((this.DateFrom >= b.DateFrom) && (this.DateFrom <= b.DateTo)) ||
                                  ((this.DateTo >= b.DateFrom) && (this.DateTo <= b.DateTo)) ||
                                  ((this.DateFrom <= b.DateFrom) && (this.DateTo >= b.DateFrom) && (this.DateTo <= b.DateTo)) ||
                                  ((this.DateFrom >= b.DateFrom) && (this.DateFrom <= b.DateTo) && (this.DateTo >= b.DateTo)) ||
                                  ((this.DateFrom <= b.DateFrom) && (this.DateTo >= b.DateTo))
                            select b;


        var availableRooms = GetRooms().Where(r => !roomsBooked.Any(b => b.RoomID == r.ID));
```

The above code first selects all the rooms that are booked and places them in the `roomsBooked` collection.  There after, I call the `GetRooms()` function, that will get all the rooms in your "Database". I then do a `where()` to filter out all the rooms from the `GetRooms()` that are not currently in the `roomsBooked` list/collection. I hope this makes some sense

Comment: i have implemented your code but stil the search is not working correctly. i have 2 entries(room1, room2) in table room. i have one booking for room1 from 5 may 2016 to 10 may 2016. when i select 11 may 2016 as datefrom and 13 may 2016 as to, i get no record. but when i choose 5 may 2016 as date from to 10 may 2016 as date to i get the correct responding records. i dont get any record when i choose a date range when there is no record.

Comment: just curious, what did I use if not Linq

Comment: @AatishKumar I have updated my code in the sample above that you can copy and paste.  The reason it was not filtering out all rooms, is because the roomsBooked collection was empty.  I have added a check to see if the roomsBooked collection was empty, and if so, simply just return all rooms, since none of them are booked.

Comment: @AD.Net You made more use of Extension methods, which pretty much is the same thing, I just wrote it out in a LINQ query. Apologies, but my wording might have not been the best suited.

Comment: @monstertjie_za there is a scenario when the code above does not work. lets say Room 1 is booked from 15 May 2016 to 17 May 2016 and Room 2 is booked from 19 May 2016 to 22 May 2016. If i choose 14 May 2016 as Date From and 23 May 2016 i should not get Room 1 and Room 2. but with the above code i did get the records even after i added this line ` (thisDate.DateFrom <= b.DateFrom) && (thisDate.DateTo >= b.DateTo)`

Comment: @AatishKumar Please test now. I have updated the code and the query, and should match your requirements now.  If you have any further issues, maybe we should take this to private chat, and I can try and help you

Comment: @AD.Net I think the poster meant you used linq to sql which is not exactly the same as linq

Comment: @AatishKumar Did my solution above help you?

Answer (score 1):

```
var bookings = _BookingService.GetBookings()
        .Where((b => b.DateFrom > thisDate.DateFrom || 
               b.DateFrom < thisDate.DateFrom 
                     && b.DateTo > thisDate.DateTo 
                          || b.DateTo < thisDate.DateTo);

var a = _RoomService.GetRooms().Where(a => !bookings.Any(b=>b.RoomID == a.ID)).ToList());
```

Comment: i have implemented your code but stil the search is not working correctly. i have 2 entries(room1, room2) in table room. i have one booking for room1 from 5 may 2016 to 10 may 2016. when i select 11 may 2016 as datefrom and 13 may 2016 as to, i get no record. but when i choose 5 may 2016 as date from to 10 may 2016 as date to i get the correct responding records. i dont get any record when i choose a date range when there is no record.

Comment: @AatishKumar, I'd check your logic to get the `bookings` first. Try checking the logic in hand first, usually you'd need a combination of From and To dates. 

The last line is what you were actually asking for.

Comment: i added this code but still i do not get the right result `var roomsBooked = from b in _BookingService.GetBookings()
                               where (b.DateFrom >= thisDate.DateFrom) && (b.DateTo <= thisDate.DateTo) ||
                               (b.DateTo >= thisDate.DateFrom) && (b.DateFrom <= thisDate.DateTo) ||
                               (b.DateTo <= thisDate.DateFrom) && (b.DateFrom >= thisDate.DateTo)
                               select b;`   `var availablerooms = _RoomService.GetRooms().Where(a => roomsBooked.Any(b => b.RoomID != a.ID));